# D3: Efficient visualization of a complex directed acyclic graph (project dependencies)

Tags: d3.js, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am currently exploring a large proprietary code base with many individual projects and interdependencies. To get a better overview, I would like to create a graphical representation of the dependencies, which are represented by a directed acyclic graph. The hope is, to finally better understand dependency clusters and (with knowledge about the individual project's contents) to aid restructuring of projects and dependencies.

Currently, I am using D3 for the visualization. Below is the full code of my current attempt (with project names replaced by a dummy). As you can see, it still looks pretty messy. Some order can be seen when hovering over project nodes.

I already looked at (but did not try out, yet) [d3-dag](https://github.com/erikbrinkman/d3-dag), which might be promising but only contains examples with rather small data sets.

I also thought about something like a graph using [hierarchical edge bundling](https://observablehq.com/@d3/hierarchical-edge-bundling), but there is not really a hierarchy here.

Does anybody have a recommendation for a better approach than the currently used force simulation layout?

[image: project dependencies]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #controls {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    width: 20%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 10%;
  }
  
  #chart {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  path.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #c5c5c5;
    stroke-width: 1.0px;
  }
  
  circle {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  text {
    fill: #000000;
    font: 11px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  .ingoing {
    stroke: #237690!important;
    stroke-width: 1.5px!important;
  }
  
  .outgoing {
    stroke: #FA1209!important;
    stroke-width: 1.5px!important;
  }
  
  .selected {
    stroke: #000000!important;
    stroke-width: 1.5px!important;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="controls">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb_hierarchical" checked="True" onclick='redraw();'>Order by dependency chain<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb_curved" checked="True" onclick='redraw();'>Curved Lines<br>
  </div>
  <script>
    graph = JSON.parse('{"directed": true, "graph": [], "nodes": [{"id": 0, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 1, "name": "Project", "level": 2}, {"id": 2, "name": "Project", "level": 12}, {"id": 3, "name": "Project", "level": 12}, {"id": 4, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 5, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 6, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 7, "name": "Project", "level": 9}, {"id": 8, "name": "Project", "level": 1}, {"id": 9, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 10, "name": "Project", "level": 12}, {"id": 11, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 12, "name": "Project", "level": 10}, {"id": 13, "name": "Project", "level": 4}, {"id": 14, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 15, "name": "Project", "level": 6}, {"id": 16, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 17, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 18, "name": "Project", "level": 9}, {"id": 19, "name": "Project", "level": 9}, {"id": 20, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 21, "name": "Project", "level": 13}, {"id": 22, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 23, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 24, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 25, "name": "Project", "level": 0}, {"id": 26, "name": "Project", "level": 6}, {"id": 27, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 28, "name": "Project", "level": 15}, {"id": 29, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 30, "name": "Project", "level": 9}, {"id": 31, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 32, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 33, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 34, "name": "Project", "level": 2}, {"id": 35, "name": "Project", "level": 12}, {"id": 36, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 37, "name": "Project", "level": 6}, {"id": 38, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 39, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 40, "name": "Project", "level": 6}, {"id": 41, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 42, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 43, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 44, "name": "Project", "level": 15}, {"id": 45, "name": "Project", "level": 1}, {"id": 46, "name": "Project", "level": 12}, {"id": 47, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 48, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 49, "name": "Project", "level": 1}, {"id": 50, "name": "Project", "level": 14}, {"id": 51, "name": "Project", "level": 1}, {"id": 52, "name": "Project", "level": 6}, {"id": 53, "name": "Project", "level": 15}, {"id": 54, "name": "Project", "level": 15}, {"id": 55, "name": "Project", "level": 9}, {"id": 56, "name": "Project", "level": 4}, {"id": 57, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 58, "name": "Project", "level": 1}, {"id": 59, "name": "Project", "level": 1}, {"id": 60, "name": "Project", "level": 15}, {"id": 61, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 62, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 63, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 64, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 65, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 66, "name": "Project", "level": 1}, {"id": 67, "name": "Project", "level": 14}, {"id": 68, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 69, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 70, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 71, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 72, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 73, "name": "Project", "level": 6}, {"id": 74, "name": "Project", "level": 2}, {"id": 75, "name": "Project", "level": 7}, {"id": 76, "name": "Project", "level": 4}, {"id": 77, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 78, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 79, "name": "Project", "level": 4}, {"id": 80, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 81, "name": "Project", "level": 2}, {"id": 82, "name": "Project", "level": 16}, {"id": 83, "name": "Project", "level": 13}, {"id": 84, "name": "Project", "level": 12}, {"id": 85, "name": "Project", "level": 11}, {"id": 86, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 87, "name": "Project", "level": 9}, {"id": 88, "name": "Project", "level": 2}, {"id": 89, "name": "Project", "level": 6}, {"id": 90, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 91, "name": "Project", "level": 3}, {"id": 92, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 93, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 94, "name": "Project", "level": 4}, {"id": 95, "name": "Project", "level": 1}, {"id": 96, "name": "Project", "level": 13}, {"id": 97, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 98, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 99, "name": "Project", "level": 4}, {"id": 100, "name": "Project", "level": 6}, {"id": 101, "name": "Project", "level": 8}, {"id": 102, "name": "Project", "level": 11}, {"id": 103, "name": "Project", "level": 5}, {"id": 104, "name": "Project", "level": 10}], "links": [{"source": 0, "target": 57}, {"source": 0, "target": 36}, {"source": 0, "target": 23}, {"source": 0, "target": 82}, {"source": 0, "target": 39}, {"source": 0, "target": 18}, {"source": 0, "target": 41}, {"source": 0, "target": 6}, {"source": 0, "target": 85}, {"source": 0, "target": 60}, {"source": 1, "target": 50}, {"source": 1, "target": 4}, {"source": 1, "target": 77}, {"source": 1, "target": 85}, {"source": 1, "target": 75}, {"source": 1, "target": 14}, {"source": 2, "target": 50}, {"source": 2, "target": 83}, {"source": 2, "target": 67}, {"source": 3, "target": 50}, {"source": 3, "target": 67}, {"source": 3, "target": 21}, {"source": 4, "target": 50}, {"source": 4, "target": 7}, {"source": 4, "target": 20}, {"source": 5, "target": 75}, {"source": 5, "target": 60}, {"source": 5, "target": 85}, {"source": 6, "target": 104}, {"source": 7, "target": 50}, {"source": 7, "target": 12}, {"source": 7, "target": 85}, {"source": 8, "target": 50}, {"source": 8, "target": 35}, {"source": 8, "target": 91}, {"source": 8, "target": 96}, {"source": 8, "target": 26}, {"source": 8, "target": 68}, {"source": 9, "target": 101}, {"source": 9, "target": 7}, {"source": 9, "target": 62}, {"source": 12, "target": 85}, {"source": 12, "target": 102}, {"source": 13, "target": 22}, {"source": 13, "target": 52}, {"source": 13, "target": 27}, {"source": 13, "target": 47}, {"source": 13, "target": 30}, {"source": 13, "target": 43}, {"source": 13, "target": 60}, {"source": 13, "target": 61}, {"source": 13, "target": 62}, {"source": 13, "target": 92}, {"source": 13, "target": 7}, {"source": 13, "target": 9}, {"source": 13, "target": 70}, {"source": 13, "target": 68}, {"source": 13, "target": 12}, {"source": 13, "target": 37}, {"source": 13, "target": 73}, {"source": 13, "target": 15}, {"source": 13, "target": 16}, {"source": 13, "target": 100}, {"source": 13, "target": 101}, {"source": 13, "target": 20}, {"source": 13, "target": 103}, {"source": 14, "target": 75}, {"source": 14, "target": 50}, {"source": 14, "target": 85}, {"source": 14, "target": 56}, {"source": 14, "target": 98}, {"source": 15, "target": 70}, {"source": 15, "target": 22}, {"source": 15, "target": 7}, {"source": 16, "target": 85}, {"source": 16, "target": 101}, {"source": 17, "target": 50}, {"source": 17, "target": 85}, {"source": 18, "target": 35}, {"source": 25, "target": 30}, {"source": 25, "target": 51}, {"source": 25, "target": 80}, {"source": 25, "target": 4}, {"source": 25, "target": 95}, {"source": 25, "target": 13}, {"source": 25, "target": 59}, {"source": 25, "target": 77}, {"source": 25, "target": 1}, {"source": 25, "target": 75}, {"source": 25, "target": 8}, {"source": 25, "target": 64}, {"source": 25, "target": 14}, {"source": 25, "target": 49}, {"source": 25, "target": 33}, {"source": 25, "target": 58}, {"source": 25, "target": 66}, {"source": 25, "target": 45}, {"source": 20, "target": 85}, {"source": 20, "target": 7}, {"source": 21, "target": 67}, {"source": 22, "target": 85}, {"source": 24, "target": 50}, {"source": 24, "target": 85}, {"source": 26, "target": 30}, {"source": 26, "target": 50}, {"source": 26, "target": 35}, {"source": 26, "target": 0}, {"source": 26, "target": 63}, {"source": 26, "target": 48}, {"source": 26, "target": 75}, {"source": 26, "target": 65}, {"source": 27, "target": 101}, {"source": 29, "target": 50}, {"source": 29, "target": 60}, {"source": 29, "target": 87}, {"source": 29, "target": 19}, {"source": 30, "target": 60}, {"source": 30, "target": 44}, {"source": 30, "target": 85}, {"source": 30, "target": 21}, {"source": 30, "target": 53}, {"source": 32, "target": 50}, {"source": 32, "target": 60}, {"source": 32, "target": 18}, {"source": 32, "target": 19}, {"source": 33, "target": 99}, {"source": 33, "target": 48}, {"source": 33, "target": 26}, {"source": 33, "target": 75}, {"source": 33, "target": 98}, {"source": 33, "target": 68}, {"source": 33, "target": 79}, {"source": 34, "target": 75}, {"source": 34, "target": 17}, {"source": 34, "target": 33}, {"source": 37, "target": 27}, {"source": 37, "target": 70}, {"source": 37, "target": 101}, {"source": 38, "target": 67}, {"source": 38, "target": 96}, {"source": 40, "target": 67}, {"source": 41, "target": 82}, {"source": 66, "target": 75}, {"source": 66, "target": 74}, {"source": 66, "target": 88}, {"source": 45, "target": 81}, {"source": 47, "target": 30}, {"source": 47, "target": 67}, {"source": 47, "target": 46}, {"source": 47, "target": 96}, {"source": 48, "target": 32}, {"source": 48, "target": 18}, {"source": 48, "target": 29}, {"source": 49, "target": 50}, {"source": 49, "target": 60}, {"source": 49, "target": 85}, {"source": 49, "target": 5}, {"source": 50, "target": 60}, {"source": 50, "target": 44}, {"source": 50, "target": 54}, {"source": 50, "target": 53}, {"source": 51, "target": 75}, {"source": 51, "target": 65}, {"source": 51, "target": 34}, {"source": 51, "target": 33}, {"source": 52, "target": 7}, {"source": 52, "target": 101}, {"source": 56, "target": 75}, {"source": 56, "target": 65}, {"source": 56, "target": 98}, {"source": 58, "target": 75}, {"source": 58, "target": 17}, {"source": 58, "target": 33}, {"source": 59, "target": 50}, {"source": 59, "target": 35}, {"source": 59, "target": 1}, {"source": 59, "target": 31}, {"source": 59, "target": 85}, {"source": 59, "target": 72}, {"source": 59, "target": 75}, {"source": 59, "target": 14}, {"source": 59, "target": 67}, {"source": 60, "target": 82}, {"source": 62, "target": 50}, {"source": 62, "target": 60}, {"source": 62, "target": 85}, {"source": 62, "target": 55}, {"source": 63, "target": 87}, {"source": 63, "target": 36}, {"source": 63, "target": 69}, {"source": 63, "target": 23}, {"source": 63, "target": 82}, {"source": 63, "target": 60}, {"source": 63, "target": 41}, {"source": 63, "target": 85}, {"source": 63, "target": 97}, {"source": 63, "target": 11}, {"source": 64, "target": 15}, {"source": 64, "target": 16}, {"source": 64, "target": 22}, {"source": 64, "target": 52}, {"source": 64, "target": 100}, {"source": 64, "target": 101}, {"source": 64, "target": 85}, {"source": 64, "target": 9}, {"source": 64, "target": 62}, {"source": 64, "target": 94}, {"source": 65, "target": 42}, {"source": 67, "target": 28}, {"source": 68, "target": 50}, {"source": 68, "target": 60}, {"source": 70, "target": 50}, {"source": 70, "target": 62}, {"source": 70, "target": 84}, {"source": 70, "target": 85}, {"source": 70, "target": 7}, {"source": 70, "target": 47}, {"source": 71, "target": 38}, {"source": 71, "target": 67}, {"source": 71, "target": 78}, {"source": 72, "target": 30}, {"source": 73, "target": 50}, {"source": 73, "target": 16}, {"source": 73, "target": 22}, {"source": 73, "target": 60}, {"source": 73, "target": 61}, {"source": 73, "target": 85}, {"source": 73, "target": 20}, {"source": 74, "target": 30}, {"source": 74, "target": 50}, {"source": 74, "target": 80}, {"source": 74, "target": 35}, {"source": 74, "target": 24}, {"source": 74, "target": 14}, {"source": 74, "target": 13}, {"source": 74, "target": 77}, {"source": 74, "target": 5}, {"source": 74, "target": 91}, {"source": 74, "target": 62}, {"source": 74, "target": 64}, {"source": 74, "target": 72}, {"source": 74, "target": 86}, {"source": 74, "target": 103}, {"source": 74, "target": 26}, {"source": 74, "target": 101}, {"source": 74, "target": 31}, {"source": 74, "target": 75}, {"source": 75, "target": 85}, {"source": 76, "target": 90}, {"source": 76, "target": 67}, {"source": 77, "target": 50}, {"source": 77, "target": 76}, {"source": 77, "target": 85}, {"source": 77, "target": 42}, {"source": 80, "target": 50}, {"source": 80, "target": 85}, {"source": 83, "target": 50}, {"source": 84, "target": 96}, {"source": 85, "target": 50}, {"source": 85, "target": 35}, {"source": 85, "target": 21}, {"source": 85, "target": 82}, {"source": 85, "target": 60}, {"source": 85, "target": 83}, {"source": 85, "target": 2}, {"source": 85, "target": 46}, {"source": 85, "target": 84}, {"source": 85, "target": 3}, {"source": 85, "target": 10}, {"source": 86, "target": 13}, {"source": 86, "target": 37}, {"source": 87, "target": 104}, {"source": 88, "target": 85}, {"source": 89, "target": 50}, {"source": 89, "target": 71}, {"source": 90, "target": 50}, {"source": 91, "target": 67}, {"source": 92, "target": 50}, {"source": 92, "target": 85}, {"source": 93, "target": 67}, {"source": 94, "target": 85}, {"source": 94, "target": 52}, {"source": 94, "target": 62}, {"source": 95, "target": 50}, {"source": 95, "target": 85}, {"source": 95, "target": 68}, {"source": 43, "target": 16}, {"source": 43, "target": 22}, {"source": 43, "target": 37}, {"source": 43, "target": 101}, {"source": 43, "target": 85}, {"source": 43, "target": 20}, {"source": 96, "target": 67}, {"source": 97, "target": 104}, {"source": 98, "target": 75}, {"source": 98, "target": 65}, {"source": 98, "target": 26}, {"source": 98, "target": 89}, {"source": 98, "target": 40}, {"source": 99, "target": 50}, {"source": 99, "target": 67}, {"source": 99, "target": 93}, {"source": 99, "target": 72}, {"source": 100, "target": 50}, {"source": 101, "target": 7}, {"source": 103, "target": 30}, {"source": 103, "target": 15}, {"source": 103, "target": 22}, {"source": 103, "target": 52}, {"source": 103, "target": 60}, {"source": 103, "target": 61}, {"source": 103, "target": 100}, {"source": 103, "target": 35}, {"source": 103, "target": 73}, {"source": 103, "target": 20}, {"source": 103, "target": 70}, {"source": 103, "target": 7}], "multigraph": false}')

    var cb_hierarchical = document.getElementById("cb_hierarchical");
    var cb_curved = document.getElementById("cb_curved");
    var chartDiv = document.getElementById("chart");
    var svg = d3.select(chartDiv).append("svg");

    var linkedByIndex = {};
    var num_links = {};
    var num_links_incoming = {};
    graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
      linkedByIndex[d.source + "," + d.target] = 1;
      num_links[d.target] = (num_links[d.target] != undefined ? num_links[d.target] + 1 : 1)
      num_links[d.source] = (num_links[d.source] != undefined ? num_links[d.source] + 1 : 1)
      num_links_incoming[d.target] = (num_links_incoming[d.target] != undefined ? num_links_incoming[d.target] + 1 : 1)
      d.distance = graph.nodes[d.target].level - graph.nodes[d.source].level;
    });

    const maxlevel = graph.nodes.reduce(function(currentValue, node) {
      return Math.max(node.level, currentValue);
    }, 0);
    var maxlinks = Object.values(num_links).reduce(function(currentValue, entry) {
      return Math.max(entry, currentValue);
    }, 0);

    var white_background = svg.append("svg:defs")
      .append("filter")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 1)
      .attr("height", 1)
      .attr("id", "white_background");

    white_background
      .append("feFlood")
      .attr("flood-color", "white");

    white_background
      .append("feComposite")
      .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes)
      .on('tick', tick);

    // add the links
    var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("class", "link");

    // define the nodes
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .on("mouseover", highlight(true))
      .on("mouseout", highlight(false))
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

    // add the node-circles
    var circle = node.append("circle")
      .attr("z", 0);

    // add the text to nodes
    var title = node.append("text")
      .attr("x", 12)
      .attr("z", 5)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("filter", "url(#white_background)")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }

    function tick(e) {
      var width = chartDiv.clientWidth;
      var height = chartDiv.clientHeight;

      node
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius - 75, d.x));
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y));
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

      path.attr("d", function(d) {
        if (cb_curved.checked) {
          return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "C" + d.target.x + "," + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x + "," + d.target.y + "," + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        } else {
          return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        }
      });
    }

    function highlight(active) {
      return function(d, i) {
        path.classed("ingoing", function(link) {
          return active && link.target === d;
        });
        path.classed("outgoing", function(link) {
          return active && link.source === d;
        });
        node.classed("ingoing", function(node) {
          return active && linkedByIndex[node.id + "," + d.id];
        });
        node.classed("outgoing", function(node) {
          return active && linkedByIndex[d.id + "," + node.id];
        });
        node.classed("selected", function(node) {
          return active && d.id === node.id;
        });
        circle.classed("ingoing", function(node) {
          return active && linkedByIndex[node.id + "," + d.id];
        });
        circle.classed("outgoing", function(node) {
          return active && linkedByIndex[d.id + "," + node.id];
        });
        circle.classed("selected", function(node) {
          return active && d.id === node.id;
        });
        title.classed("ingoing", function(node) {
          return active && linkedByIndex[node.id + "," + d.id];
        });
        title.classed("outgoing", function(node) {
          return active && linkedByIndex[d.id + "," + node.id];
        });
        title.classed("selected", function(node) {
          return active && d.id === node.id;
        });
      };
    }

    function redraw() {
      var width = chartDiv.clientWidth;
      var height = chartDiv.clientHeight;

      svg.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

      const radius = 25;
      const charge = 10;
      const link_strength = .75;
      graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.radius = radius * Math.atan((num_links[d.id] != undefined ? num_links[d.id] : 0) / maxlinks * 2 * Math.PI);
      });
      graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.radius_inc = radius * Math.atan((num_links_incoming[d.id] != undefined ? num_links_incoming[d.id] : 0) / maxlinks * 2 * Math.PI);
      });

      circle.attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.radius;
      });

      var leveldist = width / (maxlevel + 1);

      if (cb_hierarchical.checked) {
        simulation
          .force('x', d3.forceX()
            .x(function(d) {
              return (d.level + 0.5) * leveldist;
            })
            .strength(2.))
          .force('y', d3.forceY()
            .y(height / 2)
            .strength(0.025));
      } else {
        simulation
          .force('x', d3.forceX()
            .x(width / 2)
            .strength(0.05))
          .force('y', d3.forceY()
            .y(height / 2)
            .strength(0.05));
      }

      simulation.force('link', d3.forceLink()
          .links(graph.links)
          .strength(function(d) {
            return link_strength / d.target.radius_inc;
          })
          .distance(function(d) {
            return d.distance * leveldist
          }))
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody()
          .strength(function(d) {
            return -charge * d.radius;
          }))
        .force('collision', d3.forceCollide()
          .radius(function(d) {
            return d.radius;
          }))
        .alphaTarget(0.3)
        .restart();
    }

    redraw();
    d3.select(window).on("resize", redraw)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at Sankey diagrams with D3 js. It might be better in this case.

Comment: Hi, I finally looked at Sankey diagrams and do have the feeling that their use is very different to my case. However, I tried to adapt the idea of increasing link width with increasing number of linked nodes by making an example drawing with pen and paper. It worked well for a few projects, but when going beyond 10 projects, the quickly layout became a similar mess to the one above... :-(

Comment: A Sankey diagram is not just increasing the widths of the links. It actually performs minimization of clashes in order to separate the nodes and give better visualization. The reason I suggested Sankey is because your data looks more like a flow. I urge you to check out the api https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey

Comment: Also you could add a pan and zoom functionality to it so that it becomes easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the comments by @Coola, I extended my recent attempts with a Sankey diagram, added padding and zooming capabilities and the possibility to switch between the different visualization modes. Furthermore, I added some link drawing style, to the force simulation approach, that tries to resemble bundling of electrical wires to prevent the mess.

Posting this as an answer instead of editing the original question as the change is rather huge and contains significant progress. Hope, this is OK.

Still, things are a bit messy as you can see. Thus, I would still be happy to see more ideas.

Currently, I do have the feeling that the Hierarchical Edge bundling is best-suited for this problem. To be able to create such a graph, I introduced an artificial hierarchy indirectly via the shortest path between the main project and its dependants.

**Hierarchical Edge Bundling**
[image: Hierarchical Edge Bundling]

**Force Layout**
[image: Force Layout]

**Sankey Diagram**
[image: Sankey Diagram]

Unfortunately, the full code is too large to be posted.

Comment: Any chance of posting your code on github, et alii?  Looks like some interesting work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [networkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/drawing.html) library, first create a networkX graph and then call the layout function, I used spectral_layout as I feel it is a better way to visualize DAGs. The layout function will return a dictionary of node names with x,y positions. I did this in python, converted the dictionary to json and passed over the json to D3.